# How to pass a ref to a viewmodel correctly

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created a Textbox with placeholder text and a clear button. I've implemented it using a view model for the data context, and using a style with target type `TextBox`. In xaml, using it is pretty simple.

```xml
<TextBox DataContext="{Binding NameBox}" Style="{StaticResource placeholder}"/>
```

The way I've implemented the view model, though, smells funny to me:

```cs
public class PlaceholderTextBoxViewModel : NotifiableViewModelBase {
    private string text;

    public string Text {
        get => text;
        set {
            text = value;
            OnTextChange(text);
        }
    }

    public string PlaceholderText { get; set; }

    public RelayCommand ClearCommand => new RelayCommand(() => Text = "");

    private event Action<string> OnTextChange;

    public PlaceholderTextBoxViewModel(ref string text, string placeholderText, Action<string> changeHandler = null) {
        OnTextChange = changeHandler ?? (_ => { });
        Text = text;
        PlaceholderText = placeholderText;
    }
}
```

In case it doesn't smell too bad to you yet, check out how it's used

```cs
private string _name;
public string Name {
    get => _name;
    set {
        _name = value;
        System.Console.WriteLine(_name); // needed to silence auto prop error
    }
}

public PlaceholderTextBoxViewModel NameBox { get; }

// in the constructor...
NameBox = new PlaceholderTextBoxViewModel(ref _name, "Exam Name", t => Name = t);
```

It definitely doesn't seem right that I need to pass an explicit setter (the `changeHandler`) to the `PlaceholderTextBoxViewModel`. It seems, indeed, that the `ref` I'm passing is never really used (and is only necessary at all -- though not as a ref -- if there is to be pre-existing text in the box).

I've never used refs before and I must be doing something wrong. I have also tried pointing everything that uses the `Name` property (in the final code excerpt) to the `_name` field but that doesn't work, the field isn't properly updated, or at least isn't "communicating" its updates (in various uses, `CanExecute`s are not updated, `SearchPredicate`s are not refreshed, etc). I'm using MVVMLight, and I imagine that changing a field's value doesn't trigger `OnPropertyChanged` -- if the field's value is even changing at all.

How do I get the ref to work correctly? Am I doing this *completely* wrong?

I understand that there are other ways to implement this `TextBox` with its clear command, even in pure MVVM (namely, if I put the `ClearCommand` in the *consuming* VM instead of the textbox's VM itself, then the textbox doesn't need to have a VM at all). But I'd really like to know how to make sense of my attempted solution, if only for a better understanding of C# and of refs.

Answer (score 0):

Problem here seems to be an architectural one. MVVM is a tiered architecture that looks like this:

```
Model -> View Model -> View
```

Model is the lowest tier, view is the highest. More importantly, each tier does not have any direct visibility into any of the tiers above it.

The problem in your example is that you've broken separation of concerns. You have a parent class creating the PlaceholderTextBoxViewModel, which implies it's in the view model. However, that same class contains a "Name" property, which is actually data that should be in your model layer. Your existing architecture is such that your view model cannot see the data layer, so you've effectively had to set up your own property change notification mechanism, using the ref and delegate, to keep your model and view model synchronized.

Throw it all out, and start again. Your model should contain POCOs, so start with something like this:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

Then, when you create your view model, pass an instance of this class into its constructor so that it has visibility:

```
public class MyViewModel : NotifiableViewModelBase
{
    private MyModel Model;
    
    public MyViewModel(MyModel model) => this.Model = model;

    public string Text
    {
        get => this.Model.Name;
        set
        {
            this.Model.Name = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged(() => this.Text);
        }
    }
    // ... etc ....
}
```

I've stuck to your nomenclature of using "Name" in the model and "Text" in the view model, in practice they're usually the same, but that's up to you. Either way, you still have property change notification in your view model, and it's the view model layer updating the model layer.

Obviously there are lots of variations on this. If you don't want changes to propagate through to your model layer immediately (and there are plenty of cases where you may not want that) then give Text a backing field (_Text) and only do the synchronization at the points your want it to occur. And of course, if you want to go one step further then your model classes could instead implement interfaces, and you can use dependency injection to inject those interfaces into the view model classes instead of giving them access to the actual implementations themselves.

Above all else, keep in mind that the sole purpose of the view model is to prepare the model layer data for consumption by the view. Anything else...data, domain, business logic etc...all of that belongs in your model layer, which shouldn't have any visibility into the view model layer at all.

Answer (score 0):

The `ref` would only make sense, if you are going to change the value.

In this case you can use the `OnTextChange` event.

```
public PlaceholderTextBoxViewModel(ref string text, string placeholderText, Action<string> changeHandler = null) 
{
    OnTextChange = newValue => 
        {
            text = newValue; // <- value back to the ref
            changeHandler?.Invoke(newValue);
        }
    Text = text;
    PlaceholderText = placeholderText;
}
```

---

BTW your solution is somehow much too complicated. Keep the ViewModel as simple and abstract as possible. In this case a simple `Name` property is enough.

Leave it up the the UI developers which control they use and how they will implement a clear the control logic.

Here an example

- ViewModel

  ```
  using ReactiveUI;
  using ReactiveUI.Fody.Helpers;

  namespace WpfApp1
  {
      public class MainViewModel : ReactiveObject
      {
          [Reactive] public string Name { get; set; }
      }
  }
  ```
- View

  ```
  <Window
        x:Class="WpfApp1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="800"
        Height="450"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
      <Window.DataContext>
          <local:MainViewModel />
      </Window.DataContext>
      <Grid>
          <StackPanel
                Width="200"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
              <Label Content="{Binding Name}" />
              <DockPanel>
                  <Button 
                    DockPanel.Dock="Right" 
                    Content="x" 
                    Width="20" 
                    Click="NameTextBoxClearButton_Click"/>
                  <TextBox x:Name="NameTextBox"
                    Text="{Binding Name, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                    TextWrapping="Wrap" />
              </DockPanel>
          </StackPanel>
      </Grid>
  </Window>
  ```
- View CodeBehind

  ```
  public partial class MainWindow : Window
  {
      public MainWindow()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
      }

      private void NameTextBoxClearButton_Click( object sender, RoutedEventArgs e )
      {
          NameTextBox.Text = string.Empty;
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution would be to correct your binding. You don't have to manually forward the data by trying to implement your own change notification system.

Just make sure that your data source *always*  implements [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged?view=netcore-3.1#examples) and properly raises the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event from each property set method. Then bind directly to this properties:

```
class PlaceholderTextBoxViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private string text;
  public string Text 
  {
    get => this.text;
    set 
    {
      this.text = value;
      OnPropertyChanged();
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
  protected virtual OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
  {
    this.PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}
```

The binding syntax allows to reference nested properties.
In your special case, the `{Binding}` expression must be:

```
<TextBox DataContext="{Binding NameBox.Text}" />
```

Now the `TextBox.Text` value is automatically propagated to the `PlaceholderTextBoxViewModel.Text` property and the constructor becomes parameterless.

Comment: You've got a typo there: PropewrtyChangedEvenetArgs.